# Activity and fragment relations

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I've read Activity and Fragment sections of Android API and many Q&A on these two, but I still don't have a clear understanding of some points.

1. When android SDK creates an activity for me, it also creates a fragment for it. From what I know I can bind several fragments to one activity and switch them as I like. But I don't understand if I ever have to add any components to activity xml file? I mean all layouting and buttons are in fragment xml. In what situations and why would I need to use activity's xml file? Can I make buttons, for instance, both in activity xml and fragments xmls? Is it a good practice?
2. What logic should be generally implemented in activity class and what in its fragment? For example, I think that Fragment class is needed only to get data from UI and pass it to activity. Is that right?

Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An activity is basically a screen in your application (think of it as like a webpage) with all associated logic.  A fragment is a sub-activity, a portion of an activity with its own set of logic and UI.

You should use a fragment when either you use the same UI in multiple activities, when you want large parts of your activity's UI to change in and out as people take actions, or when you want to rearrange large parts of your UI in different layouts.  When none of those are true you should ignore fragments and just use activities directly.  In my experience it ends up being about 80% activities and 20% fragments, but it really depends on what type of apps you're developing-  tablet apps use a lot more fragments, for example, because they have more screen real estate.